# autofs on centos 6.8 to mount windows share: How to debug?

Tags: centos, windows, autofs

I am following the "even better method" documented here:

https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WindowsShares

I am unable to get it to work. I follow all the steps, but end up with no access to the windows share.

Questions:

1) Where is the autofs log file , so I can debug? (I already set the log option in autofs.conf to verbose)

2) my auto.mymount is:

```
WindowsServer  -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,user=localuser\backupuser,pass=cheesy ://winhost.mydomain.com/backups
```

I think the "localuser\backupuser" is a poss problem. But that server is in a domain, so I need to specify where the user lives. How to handle?

Suggestions and guidance welcome.

Comment: `\b` likely a problem.  Man page for mount.cifs ( https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs ) says use simply `/`, so `localuser/backupuser` in your case.

Comment: @steve Thanks. Tried that, still doesnt work. Where does autofs keep logs?

Comment: File `/etc/sysconfig/autofs`, add `OPTIONS="--debug"` and then restart autofs.  Hey presto, debug info in `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/316820/117549 ?

Answer (score 1):

How to debug:

1. modify `/etc/sysconfig/autofs`. Append this line at the end: 
   `OPTIONS="--debug"`

How to resolve your issue:
suppose you want to bind Linux `/mnt/remote/WindowsServer`  with Windows shared folder `//winhost.mydomain.com/backups`. At winhost.mydomain.com you've registered local user 'backupuser'. You have already installed and started nfs and autofs services.

1. add below line at `/etc/auto.maste`r :

   ```
   /mnt/remote    /etc/auto.mymount  --timeout=60
   ```
2. add below line at /etc/auto.mymount :

   ```
   WindowsServer  -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,domain=winhost,user=backupuser,pass=cheesy ://winhost.mydomain.com/backups
   ```
3. restart autofs:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart autofs
   ```